# Error Handling of column name in SQL giving incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Employee table Address column doesn't exist. I'm using below code for error handling.

```
IF EXIST ( select * from INFORMATION.SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME='Address')
BEGIN
select Address from Employee
END
ELSE
select 'Column Doesnt Exist' as Results
```

But I'm getting below error

> Invalid column name 'Address'

It should below result

| Results |
| --- |
| Column Doesnt Exist |

Comment: SQL is a static language, hence it attempts to parse `select Address from Employee` when you run the code, not based on the if statement. Side note you are missing a bracket in your first select.

Comment: Any alternate solution handle this scenario?

Comment: Design your database correctly? Database design is not intended to be dynamic... therefore you shouldn't need to check whether the column exists,

Comment: Honestly, I think that getting the error is the better option, than getting a column of a different name to the expectation (`Address`) with a nonsense value in it (as it's effectively an error). This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec` to make your script dynamic

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME='Address')
BEGIN
  exec ('select Address from Employee')
END
ELSE
  select 'Column Doesnt Exist' as Results
```